# Count rows on realted tables (two or more)

Tags: sql, count, left-join, row

My example is a bit stupid but the best which came in my mind ;)

```
Zoo
===
Id
Name

Animal
=======
Id
Species
ZooId

Zookeeper
=========
Id
FullName
ZooId
```

With the following Rows in there:

```
Zoo
===
1, New York
2, Berlin

Animal
======
1, Tiger, 1
2, Monkey, 1
3, Bear, 1
4, Tiger, 2
5, Zebra, 2

Zookeeper
=========
1, John Doe, 1
2, Peter Smith, 2
3, Ronald Jackson, 2
4, Michael Miller, 2
```

My expected output should be:

```
New York, 3, 1
Berlin, 2, 3
```

I tried the following query, but it's nonsense.

```
SELECT Zoo.Name, COUNT(Animal.Id) AS Animals, COUNT(Zookeeper.Id) AS Zookeepers
FROM Zoo
LEFT JOIN Animal ON Animal.ZooId = Zoo.Id
LEFT JOIN Zookeper ON Zookeeper.ZooId = Zoo.Id
GROUP BY Zoo.Name
```

I got the same count for both columns and it takes minutes for even small data-sets.

Comment: Use indexing on your columns like `Animal.ZooId`, `Zookeeper.ZooId`

Comment: COUNT(Zookeeper.Id) perhaps ?

Comment: All the relevant fields have an index. I've edited my post I meant COUNT(Zookeeper.Id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT z.Name, 
       COALESCE(a.Animals, 0) Animals, 
       COALESCE(k.Zookeepers, 0) Zookeepers
  FROM Zoo z LEFT JOIN 
( 
  SELECT zooid, COUNT(*) Animals
    FROM animal
  GROUP BY zooid
) a ON z.id = a.zooid LEFT JOIN 
( 
  SELECT zooid, COUNT(*) Zookeepers
    FROM zookeeper
  GROUP BY zooid
) k ON z.id = k.zooid
```

Output:

```
|      NAME | ANIMALS | ZOOKEEPERS |
------------------------------------
|  New York |       3 |          1 |
|    Berlin |       2 |          3 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38a55/1)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
select  t1.nm,t2.Animal_count,t3.Zookeeper_count
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN 
(select t22,count(Animal) AS Animal_count from Table2 group by(t22)) t2
ON t1.id=t2.t22
INNER JOIN 
(select t32,count(name) As Zookeeper_count from Table3 group by(t32)) t3
ON t1.id=t3.t32
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/44da0/13)